# Hierarchical file-system application Schema problem?

Tags: php, apache-flex, treeview, tree

I am creating an web application in which users can upload documents, create folders (just like any file explorer) problem Is how should I translate this Hierarchical structure into Mysql database flat structure, how should I creat a tree view from database? 
Backend (php,mysql,linux)
Frontend (flex)
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create your table which describe your files hierarchy like this

```
item_id | name/descriptio/other rows you need  | parent_item_id
```

Later when you will build the xml representation with complete and nice hierarchy, you will start from root directory, which will have parent_item_id = 0 (or null), and item_id = 1, this will be your first current_item_id. You add it as xml node to your xml. Than you will start recursively select items which have parent_item_id=current_item_id, and add them as a child nodes to current xml node.

All hard work, recursion will make for you.